# will adding .gitconfig in repository override my global .gitconfig file configurations?

Tags: git, github, tfs, git-tfs

I am having my project hosted in TFS-GIT server. I am having an issue with pull request merges on TFS . one option is to update git configs on TFS server itself to make "merges --no--ff" because of time crunch and other issues that cannot be done sooner . I am looking for a workaround for this issue

If i add .gitconfig file to the repository with merge .ff and pull.ff to false will that override configs applied at repository level ? will that work like that with git?

Any help is greatly appreciated