# Git alias behaves differently from original

Tags: git

I created an alias for `git status` with `$ git config --global alias.st status`. However, when I type `git st`, untracked files are not displayed. The output is a subset of what `git status` prints (the list of staged and modified files is the same). What could be causing this?

Comment: What is the output of `git --local --list`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35616236

Comment: Works for me as designed — the alias prints exactly the same as `git status`. Please show the output of `git config alias.st`,  `git st`,  and `git status`.

Comment: @mkrieger1: `$ git --local --list`

`Unknown option: --local`

`usage: git [--version] [--help] [-C <path>] [-c name=value]

           [--exec-path[=<path>]] [--html-path] [--man-path] [--info-path]

           [-p | --paginate | --no-pager] [--no-replace-objects] [--bare]

           [--git-dir=<path>] [--work-tree=<path>] [--namespace=<name>]

           <command> [<args>]`

Comment: Sorry, I meant `git config —local —list`. But you've hopefully figured that out already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `git config --show-origin --get-regexp "alias.*"` will show you if there are any local alias which would override your global one.

An `which git-st` or where `git-st` will check if there is any executable `git-st` which would override your alias.

Check also if you don't have any wrapper for `git` itself.

---

The [OP Bulletmagnet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2064196/bulletmagnet) confirms in the comments:

> Running `git config --show-origin --get-regexp "alias.*"` revealed that the repo itself had a `.git/config` file containing `alias.st status -uno`.

That would be a *local* configuration indeed, which would override any global/system one.

Comment: Running `git config --show-origin --get-regexp "alias.*"` revealed that the repo itself had a `.git/config` file containing  `alias.st status -uno`.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet Well spotted. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.